# How do I make it so my character does not move with my vehicle

Tags: unreal-engine4

I am currently making a game on unreal engine 4 using blueprints and I have a First-person character. When it jumps onto a truck I want it to not move with the truck so can anyone please help me with this and that would be great thankyou.

Comment: I don't understand the motive behind this? Isn't the whole point of a vehicle is that the people inside it move with it? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Hi there. must of been unclear, so the character would jump on top of the vehicle as if he was standing but I want it so that it doesn't get dragged with the truck and that it can slide off. Examples of this could be the game cluster truck.

Answer (score 0):

You Should do launch Character in speeds of 0,0,0 and override xy and z, when it hits the truck.